# Efficient algorithm for pixel neighborhood difference in OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, pixel

I was reading [this](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~cfshan/papers/shan-etal-pr07.pdf) and [this](http://www.research.att.com/people/Gibbon_David_C/library/publications/dg19960101120000.pdf) paper about hand/head tracking. They both talk about detecting motion computing the difference in a neighborhood of each pixel and comparing the result with a threshold:

Quoting from the first paper:

> We use the temporal differencing method described in Ref. [41], which computes the absolute value of differences in the neighborhood surrounding each pixel, and then derive the accumulated differ- ence by summing the difference of all neighboring pixels. When the accumulated difference is above a predetermined thresh- old, the pixel is assigned to the moving region.

Is there an efficient way to do it (possibly in OpenCV)? 
The code I wrote is pretty naive and, besides losing the real-time, seems not to give better results than a simpler pixel-to-pixel difference:

```
template<class T> class Image {
private:
    IplImage* imgp;
public:
    Image(IplImage* img=0) {imgp=img;}
    ~Image(){imgp=0;}
    void operator=(IplImage* img) {imgp=img;}
    inline T* operator[](const int rowIndx) {
        return ((T *)(imgp->imageData + rowIndx*imgp->widthStep));}
};

typedef Image<unsigned char>  BwImage;
typedef Image<float>          BwImageFloat;


void computeMovingRegion( IplImage* prev,  IplImage* cur, IplImage *mov) {

    BwImage _prev(prev);
    BwImage _cur(cur);
    BwImage _mov(mov);

    for (int i = 3; i<prev->height-3; i++) {
        for (int j=3; j<prev->width-3; j++) {

            int res=0;

            for (int k=i-3; k<i+3; k++) 
                for (int n=j-3; n<j+3; n++) 
                    res += abs(_cur[k][n] -_prev[k][n]);

            if (res>2000) {
                _mov[i][j]=_cur[i][j];
            }
            else
                _mov[i][j]=0;

        }
    }
}
```

Images are in grayscale. Don't think it matters, but I'm using MacOS 10.8 and Xcode 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able remove a lot of the redundancy if you first calculate the absolute difference image (i.e. `abs(_cur[] - prev[])`) and then just iterate over this. There are a lot more optimisations you can do beyond this, but this would be a good start for relatively little effort.

Also note that your loop indexing looks wrong - if you want to do a 7x7 neighbourhood operation it should be:

```
for (int k=i-3; k<=i+3; k++) 
    for (int n=j-3; n<=j+3; n++) 
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right my code is very redundant, I changed it computing first a "difference" image and than iterating over it as you suggested. Still the result seems a little jerky, what else can I do?

Comment: The next optimisation is to keep separate sums for 7 columns of 7 pixel abs diff values as you iterate across each row. For each new pixel you just calculate the sum of one new column, discard the oldest column and then sum the 7 columns, that way you do 6+6=12 operations per pixel instead of 7*7-1=48 operations per pixel. That should give you another 4x throughput improvement.